# Json not parsed into object/array

Tags: javascript, json

I am retriving data from MongoDB in NodeJS and trying to get the elements into a javascript array.

The data doesn't seem to get parsed into jsonParsed.

What am I missing?

```js
var jsonData = '{"GTO": 2000.0, "GAME": 100.0, "SBD": 0.0, "RVR": 1000.0, 
"BTC": 0.01153921, "JNT": 5000.0, "ETH": 10.20597219, "MUSIC": 100000.0, 
"ENJ": 200.0}';
var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);

console.log(jsonParsed)

var i;
for (i=0;i < jsonParsed.length; i++){
    console.log(jsonParsed[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your JSON represents an object, not an array.

Comment: Also, `jsonData` is an invalid string. Either move the string to a single line or use back ticks (\`) to create a multi-line string using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: If you've the line-breaks in the middle of the string in your real code, that's a syntax error breaking the code. Adjust the output filter of the console to see the error messages.

Comment: I believe, your data which was getting from mongoose is already an object. You don't need to parse into JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant break strings by new line(pressing enter) if so you need to concatenate the strings by `+`. Or you can use `` in ES6 to break strings into multiple lines

```js
var jsonData = '{"GTO": 2000.0, "GAME": 100.0, "SBD": 0.0, "RVR": 1000.0, '+
'"BTC": 0.01153921, "JNT": 5000.0, "ETH": 10.20597219, "MUSIC": 100000.0, '+
'"ENJ": 200.0}';
var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);

console.log(jsonParsed)

var i;
for (i=0;i < jsonParsed.length; i++){
    console.log(jsonParsed[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like that?

```js
var jsonString = `{
  "op": "create",
  "collection": "test",
  "args": [
    { "a": 1 },
    { "b": 2 },
    { "c": 3 }
  ]
}`
var output = [];
var config= JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log ("op is"+ config.op);
console.log("keys:")
for(var x of config.args){
  for(var key in x){
    console.log(x[key]);
    output.push(x[key]);
  }
}
console.log("Final Array:")
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the MongoDB actually returns an object **(otherwise you really should check that your model is configured correctly)** and that the quotation marks are just typos.

If your goal is to create an array of objects.. `[{...}, {...}]`

You can do something like the following:

```js
var jsonData = {"GTO": 2000.0, "GAME": 100.0, "SBD": 0.0, "RVR": 1000.0, "BTC": 0.01153921, "JNT": 5000.0, "ETH": 10.20597219, "MUSIC": 100000.0, "ENJ": 200.0}

const newArr = Object.entries(jsonData).map(([key, price]) => {
 return {[key] : price}
})


console.log(newArr)
```

You almost might need a **polyfill** for older editions of Node. If you get an error that says `Object.entries` is not a function, run this before executing your logic:

```
if (!Object.entries) {
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
  };
}
```

Comment: Better use reduce. Its much more cleaner.

Comment: Looks like what I am trying to do but I get:
const newArr = Object.entries(jsonData).map(([key, price]) => {
                      ^
TypeError: Object.entries is not a function

Comment: @Justin, that's strange Object.entries() is native javascript. Have you tried just copying the code snippet? Where are you executing this logic :o

Comment: @ChristopherNgo copy and paste and running in nodeJS v6.17.0

Comment: Its my nodeJS version as it works fine from my destop on v 10.15.3

Comment: Oh sweet, @Justin so you're no longer experiencing the issue on desktop. :) Is that the data structure you want?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Can't get it working on AWS but that a separate issue.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Justin you're welcome, I added something that might help you with your AWS problem. Try running that before executing your data-parsing logic. Let me know if that works, and please do consider upvoting and marking my solution as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve the solution for your problem

```
var jsonData = '{"GTO": 2000.0, "GAME": 100.0, "SBD": 0.0, "RVR": 1000.0, 
"BTC": 0.01153921, "JNT": 5000.0, "ETH": 10.20597219, "MUSIC": 100000.0, 
"ENJ": 200.0}'

var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var keys = Object.keys(jsonParsed)
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
 console.log(jsonParsed[keys[i]])
}
```

Comment: That works to get the values associated with each key based on the i integer.  How can I access the items using the alpha string as the key?

Comment: you mean like this `jsonParsed["GTO"]` this will fetch you the value corresponding to it `2000.0`

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to achieve.